# WPF how to easily chain animations in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a canvas:

```
<Canvas x:Name="testCanvas" Height="40" Width="460" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Image Source="versus2-top-p1.png"/>
    <Label x:Name="testLabel" Content="TEST" />
</Canvas>
```

I am animating it as follows:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    testCanvas.BeginAnimation(Canvas.MarginProperty,
        new ThicknessAnimation(new Thickness(0, -40, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    );

    testLabel.Content = "ANIMATION TEST";

    testCanvas.BeginAnimation(Canvas.MarginProperty,
        new ThicknessAnimation(new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    );
}
```

The problem is the animations don't chain. All 3 lines of code are getting fired off at the exact same time. I want to run these three lines of code in sequence:

1. Move top margin to -40
2. Change text within testLabel
3. Move top margin to 0

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out... using the animation.Completed event handler.

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ThicknessAnimation animate = new ThicknessAnimation(new Thickness(0, -40, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        animate.Completed += new EventHandler(animate_Completed);

        testCanvas.BeginAnimation(Canvas.MarginProperty, animate);
    }

    private void animate_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        testLabel.Content = "ANIMATION TEST";

        testCanvas.BeginAnimation(Canvas.MarginProperty,
            new ThicknessAnimation(new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        );
    }
```

Comment: The best way to achieve problems like your's is using the Storyboard. Check it out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative in code behind to using the Completed event to start the next animation you could put all the subsequent animations in a single storyboard and set their BeginTimes.

The nice thing about this is that you do not end up with a collection of methods and you can control (start, pause, stop, speed up)  the animation using the storyboard.

That said, I would still consider the animation as a Xaml resource a better option. To pass parameters to the animation you can use data binding and I consider the readability/maintainability of Xaml animations to be superior to C# coded animations.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var moveTopUpDuration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    var storyboard = new Storyboard();

    var moveTopUp = new ThicknessAnimation(
                        new Thickness(0, -40, 0, 0), 
                        moveTopUpDuration);
    Storyboard.SetTarget(moveTopUp, testCanvas);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(moveTopUp, Canvas.MarginProperty);
    moveTopUp.Completed += MoveTopUpCompleted;

    var moveTopDown = new ThicknessAnimation(
                          new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
                          TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(moveTopDown, testCanvas);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(moveTopDown, Canvas.MarginProperty);
    moveTopDown.BeginTime = moveTopUpDuration;

    storyboard.Childeren.Add(moveTopUp);
    storyboard.Childeren.Add(moveTopDown);       

    storyboard.Begin();
}

private void MoveTopUp_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    testLabel.Content = "ANIMATION TEST";
}
```

Comment: Could you post code on how to storyboard what I wanted to do?