# Shining star in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a star in my program:

```
<Grid>
    <Path Name="starPath" Fill="White" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="White" 
          Data="M 127,37 L 104,105 L 34,105 L 91,150 L 69,218 L 127,176 L 187,218 L 164,150 L 223,105 L 151,105 L 127,37">
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

I want star brights, lights up and lights down **slowly** and repeat this forever, with change color of the stroke of the path by animation.

I used this code, slowly lights up but quickly lights down and repeat:

```
ColorAnimation animation;
animation = new ColorAnimation();
this.starPath.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
animation.To = Colors.White;
animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(900));
animation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
this.starPath.Stroke.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animation);
```

how star lights down slowly?

Comment: Not sure if I fully understood the problem but have you tried adding `animation.AutoReverse = true;`?

Comment: exactly!

thank you very much.

Comment: Ok, then I'll post it as answer

Comment: but what about if I want reverse animation did in special duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line:

```
animation.AutoReverse = true;
```

This causes the animation to run once again in the other direction before repeating again from the beginning.

If you want other parameters (i.e. duration) for the reverse direction, you can use a `Storyboard`, see this example:

[WPF how to easily chain animations in code behind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436298/wpf-how-to-easily-chain-animations-in-code-behind)